# Ansible vmware_guest_powerstate ignoring state_change_timeout

Tags: python, ansible

Maybe I should ask this in the github project page, but I'm not sure it is a bug or just me being unable to use the functionality.

```
  tasks:
  - name: poweroff vms
    vmware_guest_powerstate:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
    port: "{{ vcenter_port }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_validate_certs }}"
    name: "{{ item.vm_name }}"
    state: shutdown-guest
    state_change_timeout: 300
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{ var_servidores}}"
```

With this code, I can shutdown the vms that belong to the list "var_servidores", but play will finish immediatly regardless of "state_change_timeout".

I tried to look at the code of the module, but I fail to find how this "state_change_timeout" is even used...(i'm not a developer) as it just seems to be stablish but never really being used  (https://fossies.org/linux/ansible/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest_powerstate.py)

Could you please advice if I'm not using the module correctly or if I should open an issue in https://github.com/ansible/ansible.

Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Ansible version is 2.6.4. The vCenter I'm connecting to is 6.5. My OS is Fedora 28 with latest updates installed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i just can not make that module work as expected. So I'll leave this workaround here in case someone else faces the same problem.

The workaround consists in gathering vm facts in a loop and run it 'until' condition of hw_power_state is off.

```
    - name: apaga las vms
      vmware_guest_powerstate:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
        port: "{{ vcenter_puerto }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_valida_certs }}"
        name: "{{ item.vm_nombre }}"
        state: shutdown-guest
        state_change_timeout: 300
      delegate_to: localhost
      loop: "{{ servidores }}"
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: espera hasta que las vms se apaguen
      vmware_guest_facts: 
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_ip }}"
        port: "{{ vcenter_puerto }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: "{{ vcenter_valida_certs }}"
        name: "{{ item.vm_nombre }}"
      loop: "{{ servidores }}"
      register: energia
      until: energia.instance.hw_power_status == "poweredOff"
      retries: 30
      delay: 10
```

Comment: Thank you it doesn't work for me either, I'll use your workaround